# gitbash command quick reference

Tags: git-bash

Does anyone know where I can find a quick reference for all commands in gitbash for windows? The help command covers the most important, but I can't find info on basic navigation such as getting the current directory, changing directory etc.

Comment: I found this link very useful (I come from a DOS\Windows environment) http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/unix_for_dos_users.html

Comment: Mike Gossland's answer should be the one accepted as it is the most correct one and will display all the commands that are available in a git bash environment. The accepted answer displays unix commands, of which only a small percentage are available with git bash for windows.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

from within the git bash shell type:

```
>cd /bin
>ls -l
```

You will then see a long listing of all the unix-like commands available. There are lots of goodies in there.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer as git bash also includes many executables that might not be installed by default on a linux distribution such as: curl, gpg and a tcl-tk environment.

Comment: Shot cut: `ls -l /bin` or `ll /bin`.

Comment: Is there any way to augment the binaries in here with other commonly needed tools such as base64 decoding, vim, etc?

Answer (score 17):

git-bash uses standard unix commands.

ls for directory listing
cd for change directory

more here -> http://ss64.com/bash/ 
Not all of these will work, but the file based ones mostly do.

Comment: The git-bash list is a small subset of the unix command list.

Answer (score 6):

Git command Quick Reference

```
git [command] -help
```

Git command Manual Pages

```
git help [command]
git [command] --help
```

Autocomplete

```
git <tab>
```

Cheat Sheets

- [GitHub Git cheat sheet](https://education.github.com/git-cheat-sheet-education.pdf)
- [Atlassian Git cheat sheet](https://www.atlassian.com/dam/jcr:8132028b-024f-4b6b-953e-e68fcce0c5fa/atlassian-git-cheatsheet.pdf)
- [GitLab Git cheat sheet](https://about.gitlab.com/images/press/git-cheat-sheet.pdf)
- [Tower Git cheat sheet](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/git-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

It will help you a lot
[Basic Git Commands](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457305/Basic-Git-Command-Line-Reference-for-Windows-Users)

Comment: The question wasn't about Git as much as it was about the basic Unix-style commands that come with MinGW bash.

Answer (score 0):

You should accept Mike Gossland's answer, but it can be improved a little. Try this in Git Bash:

```
 ls -1F /bin | grep '\*$' | grep -v '\.dll\*$' | sed 's/\*$\|\.exe//g'
```

Explanation:

List on 1 line, decorated with trailing `*` for executables, all files in `bin`. Keep only those with the trailing `*`s, but NOT ending with `.dll*`, then replace all ending asterisks or ".exe" with nothing.

This gives you a clean list of all the GitBash commands.